# CKEditor in Drupal adding "nofollow" and target ="_blank" to every link

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

Even if I set the target to _self in CKEDitor. It is putting this into every link, it seems to be the default and override any other setting the user picks. In CKEDitor source view it will not show _target="blank" but when the node is published the link turns into this.

a link looks like this

```
<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="#" style="color: rgb(85, 26, 139); text-decoration: none;">submitting an online application</a>
```

http://screencast.com/t/BEbaMw8SZ

I downloaded the latest CKEditor Full Package and am using it with the Drupal module.

UPDATE: I changed to TINYMCE and am getting the same issue so this is an issue with Drupal not CKEditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any module that alters links like [External Links](http://drupal.org/project/extlink), [External Links Filter](http://drupal.org/project/elf) etc? Check that.

Answer (score 0):

The same was happening to me. My problem was with Twitter module.

I've solved it unchecking the **Twitter link converter** filter in the format that was experimenting this problem (Filtered HTML in my case). This filter was adding "target=_blank" to all of my links.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may have this set in the format you have set for the wysiwyg editors. Check admin/config/content/formats/wysiwyg_editor and make sure that in 'Limit allowed HTML tags' the 'Add rel="nofollow" to all links' option is not checked.

[image]